# Add mbstring to php7.0 but not to php7.2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-18.04, mbstring

On my server there is an error message with phpmyadmin:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

there are two versions of php7:

- cli : Path => /etc/php/7.2/cli
- web : Path => /etc/php/7.0/apache2

I know the Mbstring module is not installed in Apache2:

```
sudo a2enmod mbstring
ERROR: Module mbstring does not exist!
```

So I want to install mbstring in php7.0:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
No version of the php7.0-mbstring package is available, but it exists in the database. 
This usually means that the package is missing, has become obsolete, 
or is only available from another source.
E: The package "php7.0-mbstring" does not have a version that can be installed
```

So:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
php-mbstring is already the most recent version (1: 7.2 + 60ubuntu1).
```

But it's useless with 7.2! I want mbstring for 7.0!

How can I do ?

Comment: Upgrade the Apache version of PHP to 7.2? Or better - 8.0.

Comment: thank you for the answer ... but I am afraid to update and therefore disrupt my CMS. Don't you think the same?